# Problems while trying to Read Binary File C++

Tags: c++, file, binary, ifstream, cer

I'm writing a simple console application in Visual Studio C++. I want to read a binary file with `.cer` extension to a byte array.

```
ifstream inFile;
size_t size = 0; 
char* oData = 0;
inFile.open(path, ios::in|ios::binary);

if (inFile.is_open())
{
    size = inFile.tellg();     // get the length of the file
    oData = new char[size+1];  //  for the '\0'
    inFile.read( oData, size );
    oData[size] = '\0' ;       // set '\0'

    inFile.close();
    buff.CryptoContext = (byte*)oData;
    delete[] oData;
}
```

But when I launch it, I receive in all the `oData` characters the same char, every time another one, For example:

```
oData = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@...".
```

Then I tried another way:

```
std::ifstream in(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

if (in)
{
    std::string contents;

    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    contents.resize(in.tellg());

    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());

    in.close();
}
```

Now the content has very strange values: a part of the values is correct, and a part is negative and strange values (maybe it is related to `signed char` and `unsigned char`?).

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: The line `in.read( &contents[0], contents.size() )` is *probably* undefined behaviour, and *definitely* a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting CryptoContext to point to your data by `byte` pointer, and after that you delete that data!

```
buff.CryptoContext = (byte*)oData;
delete[] oData;
```

After this lines CryptoContext is pointing to released and invalid data. Just keep `oData` array longer in memory and delete it after you are done with decoding or whatever you are doing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first version:

What makes you think that `tellg` gets the size of the stream? It does not, it [returns the current read position](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/). You then go on to give a pointer to your data to `buff.CryptoContents` and promptly delete the data pointed to! This is very dangerous practice; you need to copy the data, use a smart pointer or otherwise ensure the data has the correct lifespan. It is likely the deletion is stomping your data with a marker to show it has been deleted if you're running in debug mode which is why you are getting the stream of identical characters.

I suspect your suggestion about signed and unsigned may be correct for the second but I can't say without seeing your file and data.